When do the nonzero eigenvalues of a directed graph Laplacian have the same absolute value?
Question: Let $G$ be a strongly connected directed graph on $n$ vertices with Laplacian $L(G)$. Then $L(G)$ has one zero eigenvalue $\lambda_1=0$ and $n-1$ nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{n}$. Suppose the nonzero eigenvalues have constant absolute value, i.e., $|\lambda_2|=|\lambda_3|=\cdots=|\lambda_{n}|$. Can we say anything about the structure of $G$?
My thoughts: I conjecture that this implies $G$ has constant outdegree. I have a reason to believe this. There is a family of regular digraphs which satisfy the property, the doubly regular digraphs defined in this paper.

Can you tell which Laplacian you have taken?

$L(G){ij} = deg^+ (v_i)$ if $i=j$ and $-a{ij}$ if $i\neq j$. In other words $L(G)=D(G)-A(G)$ where $D(G)$ is the diagonal matrix with outdegrees and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

This is false.
Run this code in SageMath; you can do this at sagecell.sagemath.org if you do not have SageMath already installed on your own computer.
h = DiGraph('DKCYW?')
print(h.laplacian_matrix().eigenvalues())
print(h.out_degree_sequence())
h.plot()

In any case, here is the output that should see:

How did I find it?
I used the list of digraphs from Brendan McKay's website, altered the format so that SageMath can read them, and then just looked at what happened.
Warning
SageMath uses Brendan McKay's graph6 format for undirected graphs to represent a graph as string of printable characters (each character stores 6 bits of the adjacency matrix). Although Brendan also has a similar format for directed graphs, SageMath uses its own slightly different one.

Great find! How did you find this counterexample? If it was with another Sage script, it may be useful for the answer to include its source as well, so you can "teach to fish".

@FedericoPoloni Good point, I have added some extra information.

Thanks for the counterexample. I'll accept the answer. I would still be interested in knowing if there is anything positive we could say about digraphs which satisfy the property if anyone knows.

@AdityaBandekar There are not very many (small) digraphs that do have this property and lots of them look somewhat similar so it might be worth staring at a bunch of pictures to see if anything stands out.
